# Struggling with the proof of Proposition 18.5 in John Lee's Smooth Manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology

Here is the proposition: For a collection of topological spaces $\{X_j\}$, where $X = \coprod_{j} X_j$, the inclusion map $\iota_j: X_j \hookrightarrow X$ induces an isomorphism $H^k(X; \mathbb{R}) \cong \prod_{j} H^k(X_j; \mathbb{R})$. Could someone please provide some guidance? The book doesn't really explain how to do it and I am very new to these concepts. Thank you!

Comment: You have a huge typo, it is the product and not the coproduct. As the book mentions, this follows from the corresponding statement for singular homology. Which step do you struggle with? (So we know where we need to help.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I just fixed it. So I am confused how you go from $\oplus$ to $\prod$. I am still not super familiar with the definitions (this is part of a summer program I was in, and I am only now taking analysis for the first time so this is all very new to me) and I am finding it a bit difficult to find them. Any help, in either what these operations are more precisely or their connection in this case, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So it seems like your confusions only has to do with $\bigoplus, \prod$ and not with cohomology. The passage from $\bigoplus$ to $\prod$ is by the universal property of the coproduct and product. If this is too abstract, you should spell out the definitions and unravel e.g. what it means to be a map $f: A \oplus B \to C$ of modules. You should realize that it is precisely the "same thing as" two maps $f_1 : A \to C$ and $f_2 : B \to C$ or in other words an element from $\operatorname{Hom}(A,C) \times \operatorname{Hom}(B,C)$.

Comment: But there are also many many explanations of this phenomenon written out on the internet.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I had never seen this before, hence my confusion.

Comment: Well, as always in mathematics, it's never a bad idea to start by writing out the definition. ;-)